# It's vs its on social media username context

Tags: pronouns, possessives

I'm not a native speaker and just realize there is a difference between "it's" and "its".  I still have a little bit confused in some contexts. As an example, on social media sometimes we meet people who use "itsname" as their username. In this context, does it refer to "it's" or "its"?

Comment: Have you done any research about the difference between "its" and "it's"? On this site, we expect people asking questions to have done a little work themselves before asking. If you did, and you're still not sure, please edit your question to tell us what you found and what you're still unsure about. Also, check out [How to ask a good question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a rehash of a similarly confusing question from yesterday. I think at east we need more info on the "itsname" thing. I honestly can't tell what that is meant to refer to.

Comment: "itsname" is clearly meant to mean "it is name", so it would get an apostrophe (if social media sites would allow non-alphanumeric characters in usernames and if social media users would care about grammar). Also be aware that not everyone on social media will be using correct grammar in general, and specifically in cases like "its" and "it's", which confuse even native speakers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are contracting "it is" or "it has", use the apostrophe, i.e. "it's".

If you are referring to a thing, i.e. using the word as a pronoun, then leave the apostrophe out. E.g. This is my cat. Its name is Fred. This is correct.

In the above example, you're not saying "It is" name is Fred. That's why you leave it out.

It's that simple

I hope this helps.
Don't try to make it harder than that.

Comment: You seem a little confused about pronouns.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney maybe not the most precise explanation, but "its" is indeed a possessive pronoun.

Comment: @Esther [This page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc) explains the distinction clearly enough.